# Filter logs in spring-boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, configuration-files, app.yaml

In application.yml of my spring-boot application, I have the following code:

```
logging:
  file: test.log
  pattern:
    file: "%d %-5level [%thread] %logger : %msg%n"
```

I would write something like

```
 logging:
   level:
    org: hibernate: *
```

I would to filter and gather all log messages of all levels (ERROR, DEBUG, INFO, etc) ifrom only one specific package (org.hibernate) in "test.log". It is possible?

Comment: yes. it is possible

Comment: could I help you with my answer?

Comment: how ? @pvpkiran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define log level for each of your/third library packages:

Example for `application.yml`:

```
# Fine-tuning a specific logger (for a single class)
 logging:
   level:
     yourpackage: INFO
     org:
        hibernate: ALL
        springframework: INFO
```

Example for `application.properties`:

```
# Fine-tuning a specific logger (for a single class)
logging.level.yourpackage.controllers.HomeController = INFO

# Specify the level for spring boot and hibernate's loggers
logging.level.org.springframework = INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate = ALL
```

**Update 1: Only logging hibernate.* to a log file**

If you want to log only one specific Java package to your log file add a `logback.xml` to your `src/main/resources` folder and add the following settings:

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>hibernateLogs.log</file>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ALL">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

</configuration>
```

This config will log all of your hibernate logs to a file.

Comment: I know this but it does'nt qnswer the question. I need to show all messages related to a specific package. Example org:
        hibernate: *

Comment: Thanks, However we still need to set the log level with the updated solution right? which is "TRACE"

Comment: I updated the answer to TRACE for hibernate, now you should get all logs for hibernate in a seperate file

Comment: but I need all messages not only TRACE messages for hibernate